Are fold and unfold required when recursive types appear in a language?
Are fold and unfold required when recursive types appear in a language? I'm reading "Types and Programming Languages" book by Benjamin C. Pierce. Section 4, “Recursive Types,” introduces special terms fold and unfold that expand recursive types. But we can explicitly check what type a constructor belongs to and check that all patterns that match are constructors of this type. Or does this only work if recursive types are always defined via a variant type like in Haskell or ocaml? And why doesn't Haskell allow you to define recursive types that are not variant types?

No, often folding is done for recursive types, but not necessary, you can make a recursive function to handle it.

Pierce introduces fold and unfold terms in the context of a language with "iso-recursive types", but points out that both iso-recursive types (which include these terms) and equi-recursive types (which do not include these terms) are both reasonable approaches that have been used both theoretically and practically.  So, I think that's your answer:  a programming language that uses equi-recursive types has no need for fold or unfold terms.
Note that Haskell falls pretty clearly into the equi-recursive camp.  The type of lists of integers, what Pierce would call IntList and the type of its one-step unfolding, the variant type that Pierce would call <nil:Unit,cons:{Int,IntList}> are the same type in Haskell, namely the type [Int].  So, Haskell has no fold or unfold terms of the sort Pierce is talking about.
Note that this has very little to do with having fold or unfold "functions" in the standard library, the ability to explicitly check what types a constructor belongs to, or the presence or absence of variant types.
The only reason variant types might be important here is that it's difficult to make much use of recursive types without some kind of sum type, the same way it's difficult to write a recursive function without at least one base case that doesn't recurse.  Variant types are a convenient sort of sum type, but aren't absolutely necessary.  Lisp S-expressions would probably count as an equi-recursive type that isn't a variant type.
The reason Haskell requires recursive types be defined as variant types is that Haskell essentially requires all new types be defined as "variant types" (i.e., tagged unions), even in the trivial case where the type has only one variant, like:
data Pos = Pos Int Int
           ^^^- one variant!

The only exceptions are some primitive unboxed types (e.g., Int#), none of which are recursive.
